# Conduction, Convection, or Radiation

Tags: education

Am I using Conduction, Convection, or Radiation when cooking in the oven using a metal tray vs. a glass tray?

Comment: In reality, all three forms of heat transfer happen at the same time.

Comment: Hi Claudia, welcome to PhysicsSE. Radiation is ignored in this link, (though it shouldn't be in reality), but you might find it worth a read. You would be expected to show some research attempt, or your own thoughts on this.   https://www.thespruce.com/how-cooking-works-getting-food-hot-995430

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments , all heat transfer methods are present in the oven, particularly one with a fan.

In glass versus metal tray, the metal tray will heat faster than the glass one because it is more conducting and will reach the equillibrium temperature of the oven faster, by absorbing radiation and heat from convection, and spreading faster to the bottom of the food, but once there, there is no difference in the way the food is cooked, to first order. It might be that for high settings of temperature the metal tray heats faster in the thermostatic on/off, and because of conduction the bottom of the food bulk might brown and "catch" versus a glass tray that heats slower and transfers heat slower.